# How copy from opened textfile and paste while searching in vim?

Tags: vim, search

I am very new to `vim`. I know there's a lot of copy-pasting issues. I kind of like the vim's different buffer idea, but sometimes I have to work with a big text file and search for different words.

When searching for a word I press <kbd>Esc</kbd> and then write `/search_keyword`. But while starting a search by pressing <kbd>/</kbd>, I cannot paste my copied text from visual mode that I 'yanked' with <kbd>y</kbd>.

How can I paste a keyword while searching in `vim`?

Answer (score 2):

You may be able to simply press `*` to search on the current word, assuming what `*` does is appropriate.

Otherwise assuming the default yank buffer, type `/<C-r>0` which is *slash* to search, *control+r*, *zero* which should insert the contents of the `0` register. If you've yanked to some other register that could be used instead of `0`.

Comment: It says, `E486: Pattern not found: <C-r>0`. It actually searches for exact word `<C-r>0` in the text not the value of register `0` @thrig

Comment: Did you hold down the control key and then press the r key?

Comment: No I didn't. Thanks for the help. it works.